# How do I pass an array of objects into a Jade template

Tags: express, controller, pug

I have a complex array of JSON objects and I want to send that to my jade template so that so can create a visualization on the page I am rendering, but I keep having an issue with how the object is formatted.

In my controller I'm passing it like this

```
res.render('scatter', {
    title: 'Scatter',
    company: company,
    graphdata: dataArray
});
```

in my view trying to display like this

```
script graphdata = "#{graphdata}";
```

When I log the result it looks like this

```
[object Object],[object Object]
```

when it should be an array of objects.

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it happens is that it tries to convert the Array into a String.
If you take an array of Objects and convert them to a string, you will get this.

(Go to browser console and do this `[{a:4}, {k: 9}].toString()`. And the result will be `"[object Object],[object Object]"`.

If you want to display the array of Objects at it is, you can do:

```
"#{JSON.stringify(graphdata)}"
```